# Fast, efficient method of assigning large array of data to array of clusters?

Tags: labview

I'm looking for a faster, more efficient method of assigning data gathered from a DAQ to its proper location in a large cluster containing arrays of subclusters.

My current method [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRs90.png) relies heavily on the OpenG cluster manipulation tools, but with a large data-set the performance is far too slow.

The array and cluster location of each element of data from the DAQ is determined during an initialization phase and doesn't change during acquisition.

Because the data element origin and end points are the same throughout acquisition, I would think an array of memory locations could be created and the data directly assigned to its proper place.  I'm just not sure how to implement such a thing.

[image]

Comment: How is your 'Readings'  cluster setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what you want:
[image]
For each of your cluster elements (AMC, ANLG_PM and PA) you should add a case in the string case structure, for the elements AMC and PA you will need to place a second case structure.

Comment: Ton, I should have stated this in the original problem description, but I was hoping to get away from creating a case structure with statements for each and every element in the cluster.  Not only is this a bit of a pain to implement it makes the code a bit harder to maintain; I would much rather have one place that I add and subtract data elements, in the example provided that would be the typedef "Readings" cluster.  Also given that the data type for each element is the same, a dbl, a case structure for each element seems like overkill.

Comment: For the two more complex data-types, you could create a sub-vi, that takes the previous cluster, new value and channel name as inputs. Then it would replace the value and outputs the new cluster. But could you state why you need this structure?

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a comment, but I do not have the reputation to leave those yet, so here it is:

Regarding adding cases for every possible value of `Array name`, is there any reason why you cannot use an enum here? Since you are placing it into a cluster anyway, I would suggest making a type-defined enum of your possible array names. That way, when you want to add or remove one, you only have to do it in one place.

You will still need to right-click on your case structures that use this enum and select `Add item for every value` if you are adding a value, or manually delete the obsolete value if you are removing one. I suppose some maintenance is required either way...